# Are most adjectives adjuncts rather than complements?

Tags: grammar, adjectives

By this adjunct definition,

*Adjunct: an optional part of a sentence, clause, or phrase that, if removed, does not result in an ungrammatical construction.*

are *most* adjectives *adjuncts* rather than *complements*?  That is, you can omit most adjectives or elements that function as adjectives (i.e. relative clauses) without affecting grammaticality (though some information is lost, namely the information provided by adjectives).

The only type of adjectives that I can think of that function as *complements* are *predicate adjectives* (i.e. *I became sick*).

Are there other types of adjectives (besides predicate adjectives) that are *complements*?

Comment: Perhaps you might supply some sample sentences.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your question is ***yes***, there are.

In fact, adjectives can be complements in all of their six functions (that I know of):

[1]                                NON-COMPLEMENT                   COMPLEMENT
1. attributive              *That was a **legal** play.                  I need a **legal** adviser.* 
2. predicative            *He died **young**.                              He was/seemed **young**.*
3. postpositive           *I need something **general**.         He is the Surgeon **General**.*
4. predeterminer      *It is **such** a nuisance.                    It was **such** a big problem that* 
                                                                                                 *we called the police.*
5.        fused                                ?                                         ***The rich*** are to blame.
    modifier-head
6. subject                                N/A                                       ***Big*** is what you are, my boy.

In [1], in all the entries except in 5, the boldfaced words are adjective phrases (AdjPs). See below for explanations of why they are complements in the right column, but not in the left. In 5, the boldfaced words are the fused modifier-head of a noun phrase (NP).

The adjective will always be a complement in 6 (the subject); it is usually (and perhaps even always) a complement in 5 (fused modifier-head). It is most commonly a complement in 2 (predicative). In 1 and 3 (attributive and postpositive uses), adjectives are by far most commonly modifiers, but sometimes they can be complements, too. Finally, in 4 (predeterminer), they can definitely be either complements or modifiers, but I don't know which role is more common.

Let me say a bit more about 5 and 6.

In 5, the adjective functions as a **fused modifier-head** of a **noun phrase** (NP). Such an NP may be either the subject or the object:

[2]  a.  ***The rich*** are to blame.      [subject]
        b.  *Let us blame **the rich**.*        [object]

Here *the rich* is a complete noun phrase, even though it has no nouns. It functions as the subject in a. and as the object in b. Both of those functions are **complements** in the structure of the clause.

In general, NPs can appear in a number of non-complement functions as well. However, I don't know if fused modifier-head NPs ever appear in such roles. I certainly don't have a ready example.

Finally, it is even possible for AdjPs to serve as the **subject**, as in

[4] ***Big*** is what you are, my boy.

This is obviously a complement role, but not one of a predicative complement. Here we have an unusual syntax for a semantic relation that is usually expressed as *You are **big***, where *big* is a PC. I'll discuss this more below.

**Discussion**

Consider the following sentences:

[5]  a.  *These are **happy** people.*                                              [attributive]
       b.  *These people seem **happy**.*                  [predicative complement] 
       c.  *I want to meet someone **happy**.*                               [postpositive]

In all three sentences, we have the same adjective, *happy*. But in each sentence, that one and the same adjective performs a different function: it is **used** differently. In [5] a., it is used **attributively**; in b., as a **predicative complement**; and in c., **postpositively**. These are the three principal uses of adjectives. However, there are also some others; we'll get to them later.

Technically, we actually don't want to say that it is the adjectives that perform these roles. Instead, we want to say that

> Strictly speaking it is AdjPs [adjective phrases] that occur in these functions, but we can talk of attributive, predicative, and postpositive uses of an adjective with the understanding that the adjective is head of an AdjP in the function in question. The AdjP will consist of the head adjective alone or accompanied by its dependents.  (CGEL, p. 529)

In [5], the AdjPs all consist of a single adjective, *happy*. But if you replace *happy* by *very happy*, you get a more complicated AdjP. And this more complicated AdjP nicely functions in all three roles.

**Complements vs adjuncts**

***1. Attributive function***

According to [CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521431468) (p. 528),

> Attributive AdjPs are almost always modifiers rather than complements.

There are, however, some adjectives that can function attributively as complements. For example (CGEL, p. 439; the number in the original was 2 rather than 6),

> [6]  ii  a.  *a **legal** adviser*          b.  *an **ecological** expert*

Why are these complements of the noun rather than modifiers? Compare

[7]   i  *a **good** adviser* = *an adviser that is **good***
       ii  *a **legal** play* = *a play that is **legal***
      iii  *a **legal** adviser* ≠ *an adviser that is **legal***

In [7] i, *good* is a modifier (rather than a complement), and there is a correspondence between attributive and PC functions. Similarly, *legal* is a modifer in ii, and there is the same correspondence. However, in iii, there is no such correspondence. This happens with only some nouns, and for each such noun, only with some adjectives: for example, with the noun *adviser*, it happens with such adjectives as *legal*, *technical*, *medical*, etc. These adjectives are therefore **licensed** by the noun; and whenever something is licensed, it means it is a complement; that, indeed, is the basic criterion (CGEL, p. 440).

Here is another test to distinguish between modifiers and complements among the AdjPs functioning as pre-head dependents in NP structure: **the scope of anaphora** (CGEL, pp. 440-441).

> This test distinguishes between the two senses of the ambiguous 
>   nominal *criminal lawyer* (with *criminal* an adjective in both). In the sense "lawyer who works in the field of criminal law", *criminal* is a complement and resists combination with ***one***: <sup>?</sup>*I needed a civil lawyer, but he had found me a **criminal** one.* But in the sense "lawyer who is criminal", *criminal* is a modifier and combines readily with ***one***: *It turned out that he was an honest lawyer, not a **criminal** one, as I'd been led to expect.* (CGEL, p. 441.)

Now compare

[8]   i  *I prefer **good** advisors to bad ones.*
       ii  *I prefer **legal** plays to illegal ones.*
      iii  <sup>?</sup>*I prefer **legal** advisors to medical ones.*

Here [8] iii is an attempt to combine the [pro-form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro-form) ***one*** with an internal complement. Such attempts, according to CGEL, typically show 'varying degrees of infelicity'. In contrast, there is no problem when *one* is combined with a modifier, as in i and ii.

***2. Predicative complement function***

As you notied yourself, in this function, an AdjP is always a complement, really by definition. However, there is a similar role where it is an adjunct, a **predicative adjunct**. We've seen an example of that in [1]:

[1]                          NON-COMPLEMENT             COMPLEMENT
predicative            *He died **young**.                      He seemed **young**.*

*Young* is a PC in the right column, but a predicative adjunct in the left. I'll return to this below.

***3. Postpositive function***

According to CGEL (p. 529),

> Postpositive adjectives are much less frequent than attributive and predicative ones: adjectives are admissible in this position only under severe syntactic constraints.

Usually, they are modifiers, like *happy* in [5] c. However, here are some examples of a postpositive adjective functioning as complements ([*Garner's Modern American Usage*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0195161912), p. 627):

[9]    *attorney **general***
      *surgeon **general***      *postmaster **general***      *secretary **general***
        
*ambassador-**designate***      *heir **apparent***
      *president-**elect***
         *accounts **payable***      *accounts **receivable***      *annuity **certain***
         *condition **precedent***      *condition **subsequent***
         *court-**martial***      *knight-**errant***      *minister **extraordinary***
         *notary **public***      *battle **royal***      *body **politic***

First of all, I suppose an argument is required to establish that some of these are indeed adjectives. For example, in the case of *general*, if it were a noun, the plural would be e.g. **surgeon generals*, but it is not: it is *surgeons general*. *Attorney general* is an exception because in British English the plural is *attorney generals*; in American English, however, it's *attorneys general* (*Garner's Modern American Usage*, p. 617). I will not try to give a further argument, and just note that *Garner's* lists all of these as examples of postpositive adjectives.

Secondly, one should provide an argument that these adjectives are complements. This is pretty straightforward: all of these adjectives are licensed. For example, we can use *general* in this way with only a handful of nouns. The postpositive uses of the other adjectives in [9] are similarly restrictive.

**Adjectives in other functions**

While the three functions in [5] are the main functions that adjectives (that is, AdjPs) perform, sometimes they can also perform other functions. Here are some examples (CGEL, p. 529; in the original, the example number is 3, not 10):

> ■ ***Further adjectival functions***
>
> [10]  i  ***such*** a nuisance      ***so serious*** a problem                                                  [predeterminer] 
>           ii  *the **rich**      the **bigger** of the two        the most **useful** of them*    [fused modifier-head]  
>          iii  *He died **young**.       They served the coffee **blindfolded**.*              [ predicative adjunct] 
>   
>          iv  ***Furious***, he stormed out of the room.                                                 [ predicative adjunct]
>
> **Predeterminer** AdjPs occur as external modifier in NP structure, preceding the definite article *a*. This construction is subject to highly restrictive structural conditions described in §3.3. All adjectives that can head a predeterminer AdjP can also be used attributively—cf. *such tools, a serious problem*.
>
> The **fused modifier-head** AdjPs in [10ii] combine the functions of internal modifier and head in NP structure; this construction is described in Ch. 5, §9.3. All adjectives that can function in this construction can also be used attributively.
>
> Finally, the AdjPs in [10 iii—iv] function as **predicative adjunct**. Those in [10 iii] are integrated into clause structure and hence modifiers, while that in [iv] is detached and hence a supplement. All adjectives that can function as predicative adjunct can also function as predicative complement.

An AdjP in the function of a predicative adjunct is obviously not a complement (that's kind of the whole point of this special role). 
However, AdjPs functioning as predeterminers can be complements:

***4. Predeterminer function***

Consider

[11]  *[**How big** a company] is it?     It was [**so serious** a matter that we called the police].*

Here brackets enclose noun phrases, while the boldfaced words are AdjPs (CGEL, p. 551). It is pretty clear that the AdjPs are complements here; omitting them results in nonsense.

***5. The function as the fused modifier-head of an NP***

As I've discussed above, fused modifier-head AdjPs are heads of NPs, and these can function as complements in the structure of a clause (i.e. the subject and the object).

[2]  a.  ***The rich*** are to blame.      [subject]
        b.  *Let us blame **the rich**.*        [object]

***6. The subject function: semantics vs syntax***

To begin with, consider

[12] *I became **sick**.*

As far as syntax, *sick* functions as a **predicative complement** (PC). As far as semantics, it denotes a property ('being sick') that is predicated of something (the speaker).

Here the grammatical and syntactic functions align nicely: we accomplish the semantic goal of assigning a property to the speaker (*I*) by using a complex-transitive verb (*become*) with a PC complement (*sick*).

But we don't always have such a straightforward fit between syntax and semantics. Consider the sentence

[13] ***Big*** is what you are, my boy.

Semantically, this is similar to [12]: we are predicating a property ('being big') to something (*you*, 'the boy'). However, syntactically, things are very unusual: consider the word that denotes the property, *big*; technically, we should say that this is an AdjP consisting of just the head, a single adjective. This AdjP is the **subject** rather than a PC. And *what you are* is not the PC here. This we know because *is* cannot be replaced by any other verb that normally allows a PC (such as *become*, *appear*, *seem*, etc.).

The syntax of [13] is relatively complex, and it would take us too far to analyze it right now. My only point is that the main verb here (*is*) does not have a PC.<sup>1</sup>

<sup><sup>1</sup>Though the second verb, *are*, does have a PC: compare with *Big is **what you have become**, my boy.* However, *what you [are]/[have become]* is not a clause, but what's called a **fused relative noun phrase**... like I said, it's complicated.</sup>

So, is *big* in [13] a 'predicate adjective'? Semantically, yes; syntactically, no. And so, syntactically, it is an example of an adjective in complement function which is not a predicative complement. (It should be clear why it is in a complement function: the subject is always a complement.)

Comment: @Lambie I admit it has gotten out of hand. That was part of the research. I may try to trim it down... though I do have to explain *why* these things are complements, I think.

Comment: @Lambie On the other hand, the initial part, before 'Discussion', is exactly what you say it should be: a few examples (modulo the part about various non-complement uses of NPs).

Comment: Holy crap I didn't even know SE would let you submit this long of an answer.

Comment: You had me at "As I said in the main text, I don't know if fused head-modifier NPs ca

Comment: OK, I've cut out a lot of the discussion, including both appendices. It's still pretty long, but definitely much shorter than it was.

Comment: @ linguisticturn, thanks for your informative answer. I wish I'd seen your appendices before you cut them out, and I don't understand why you did so. If the answer is on point, then it is on point, regardless of length. And some of us like long answers; they give us lots of information to chew on.

Comment: @Puzzled You can still see the old versions, e.g. [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/revisions/446958/8). Take a look at it, and if you think some stuff there that was cut out really should be reintroduced, let me know. Also let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Substantive adjectives serve as nouns: "Give me your poor..."
I am not certain by what you mean as "complement," other than your example of predicate adjectives itself being similar to a substantive adjective in meaning, I became sick, really means, I became a sick person, because you did not become the generic quality of sickness itself, just acquired the attribute (hopefully briefly). 
Likewise with any predicate adjectives: I am thirsty, means, I am a thirsty person, I am thirty means, I am a 30 year-old person, etc. 
Consider also this statement using a substantive adjective, from February 24, 2016: "I love the poorly educated." 
 "https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/politics/onpolitics/2016/02/24/donald-trump-nevada-poorly-educated/80860078/
Here "the poorly educated" served as a substantive adjective using a past participle form.